# Add data to specific location in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following database structure in Firebase. Its a pretty standard way to manage users and their data in database. I am also take advantage of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` in FirebaseUI.

```
-root
 -users
   -user1
     -item0
     -item1
     -item2
     ...
   -user2
   ...
```

Now I want to implement swipe to delete / undo feature. For the swipe to delete part, I had implemented `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` method to catch `onSwiped` status. In the callback I simply update the database using

`mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(indexOfDeletedItem).removeValue();`

In this way, the swiped item immediately got removed in the database. However, when I try to restore it back. I am not able to insert to where it was. For example,

```
@Override
        public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            //get the location of swiped item. 
            final int indexOfDeletedItem = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            //I cached the item in case I need to restore it.
            final ITEM deletedItem = mFirebaseAdapter.getItem(indexOfDeletedItem);

            //remove the item on swipe
            mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(indexOfDeletedItem).removeValue();

            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), "Deleted Item", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                          //When user want to restored the deleted item
                          //I need to add the deleted data back to database.
                 mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(indexOfDeletedItem).push()setValue(deletedItem);

                                                   }
                         }).show();
    }
```

I am not able to correctly insert(add) the data into specific location ***without overwriting it.***  I think the index of item got updated immediately after I called `mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(indexOfDeletedItem).removeValue();`

For example, for `user1` I have `item0` with index `0`,

`item1` with index `1` and

`item2` with index `2`

```
 index     0      1         2

       item0 --> item1 --> item2   //now swipe on item1

       item0 --> item2             //now user click undo

       item0 --> item1             //item2 gets overwritten
```

if there a way to make it back to

```
       item0 --> item1 --> item2
```

In my case, I always overwrite the data on `indexOfDeletedItem`.

I am looking for a API to insert the node back to database without overwriting it. In other words, How can I push the node (item1) into where it was before?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about insert vs overwrite in this question. Can you edit the question to be clearer about what you want to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: I just add some example, i hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that when you are restoring the item, the reference of the adapter is changed and you are receiving a different Reference. Just make a local copy of the Databasereference before you delete the item. E.g.

```
DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseAdapter
getRef(indexOfDeletedItem);
```

Later inside the snackbar action you can just call:

```
ref.setValue(deletedItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. This is exactly what im looking for.